# Why none of xmlrpc filters work

Tags: filters, hooks, xml-rpc

I disabled all of the plugins and used fresh install of wordpress but it seems none of xmlrpc filters works for me... . for example

```
 add_filter( 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data', 'ffff' );

//or
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_default_post_fields', 'bbbb',3 );
```

I used some sort of logging into ffff and bbbb and noticed the filter wont apply... .

```
function ffff($postdata)
{
    // Check if the post title exists:
 print_to_log('we never and ever reach there');
    return $postdata;  
}
```

my function for the logging.

```
 function print_to_log( $message )
{
    if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
        if ( is_array( $message ) || is_object( $message ) ) {
            error_log( print_r( $message, true ) );
        } else {
            error_log( $message );
        }
    }
}
```

with this setting in wp.config

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );  
define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Comment: Are you sure that `wp-content/debug.log` is writable by PHP? Be careful not to immediately assume the issue is XMLRPC.

Comment: I can write to file and see its logs. also I can post to wordpress via xmlrpc

Comment: When you say *you*, you mean you've tested that *PHP* can write to the log?

Comment: Yes for example in another function when there is print_to_log('tttt); a line with "tttt" will be appended to logs while you call the function

Comment: If you check [the source of the filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_xmlrpc_server/_insert_post/), you'll see there are many possible breakpoints (returns) before it actually fires. Are you sure that everything is going smoothly otherwise, and the post is inserted when you make your XMLRPC request?